# SASS Media Query Mixin

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, media-queries

I'm trying to get my breakpoints setup following [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-responsive-breakpoints-sass/) tutorial. They are working correctly when I target just one property. When I try to create a query that targets two (width and height) it only displays the latter. I've researched the Sass functions that I'm using and it should be rendering correctly so I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm using sass-rails on Ruby on Rails version 4.2.2.

Thanx

```
$breakpoints: (
  'small'  : ( max-width:  20em ),
  'mobile' : ( min-width:  36.25em ),
  'tablet'  : ( min-width: 48em ),
  'desktop'  : ( min-width: 60em ),
  'wide'    : ( min-width: 75em ),
  'height'    : ( min-width: 75em ) and (min-height: 62.5em)  
);

@mixin media($name) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $name) {
    @media #{inspect(map-get($breakpoints, $name))} {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @else {
    @warn "Unfortunately, no value could be retrieved from `#{$breakpoint}`. "
        + "Please make sure it is defined in `$breakpoints` map.";
  }
}
```

This is what is rendered:

```
@media (min-height: 62.5em) {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally when storing media queries in *variables* or as *values* in a key value pair, they should be stored as strings. Check out these sites [Media Queries by David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/write-media-queries-sass) and [Responsive Web Design in Sass by Mason Wendell](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32)

Replace this line of code
`'height'    : ( min-width: 75em ) and (min-height: 62.5em)`
with
`'height'    : "( min-width: 75em ) and (min-height: 62.5em)"`

Now that the values passed to the mixin can either be a *string* or *list*, the mixin needs to recognise these changes

```
@mixin media($name) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $name) {
    $value: map-get($breakpoints, $name);
    $query: if(type-of($value) == "string", $value, inspect($value));
    @media #{$query} {
      @content;
    }
  }
  @else {
    @warn "Unfortunately, no value could be retrieved from `#{$breakpoint}`. "
        + "Please make sure it is defined in `$breakpoints` map.";
  }
}

$breakpoints: (
  'small'  : ( max-width:  20em ),
  'wide'    : "( min-width: 75em ) and (min-height: 62.5em) and (max-height: 100em)",
  'height'    : "( min-width: 75em ) and (min-height: 62.5em)"  
);

div.gta {
  @include media(wide) { ... }
}

div#mgs {
  @include media(height) { ... }
}
```

This compiles to the following CSS

```
@media (min-width: 75em) and (min-height: 62.5em) and (max-height: 100em) {
  div.gta { ... }
}

@media (min-width: 75em) and (min-height: 62.5em) {
  div#mgs { ... }
}
```

This will allow the mixin to be used on any number of media queries

Comment: Thanx! This worked, I don't get why it wasn't working like the tutorial stated since I copied it from there.

Can you explain what's going on in the `if` statement?? I've never seen it like that. I read the links you suggested hoping to find more info on that but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: The links just really showed that compound media queries are always stored as strings in variables. I'll try and have a look at the tutorial. I used an `if` **function** in my code. It takes 3 args comma separated, the first is the condition, second is return value if condition evaluates to true and third is return value if condition evaluates to false. Once you feel quite confident writing your own media queries, I highly recommend looking into [breakpoint](http://breakpoint-sass.com/). You won't be able to live without it afterwards.

Comment: Thanx for explaining it. So it's basically a ternary operator. I hadn't seen it like that. I thought it was a SASS thing.
And yeah, I've looked at breakpoint before. I just want learn more about mixins and functions so I can write me own in the future. That's why I decided to go with this route. But I agree breakpoint is great.
Thank you so much for explaining it and the pointers. This really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use when wanting to target more then one media query (obviously set your queries to what ever you wish):

```
$size__site_content_width : 1024px;

/* Media Queries */
$media_queries : (
    'mobile'    : "only screen and (max-width: 667px)",
    'tablet'    : "only screen and (min-width: 668px) and (max-width: $size__site_content_width)",
    'desktop'   : "only screen and (min-width: ($size__site_content_width + 1))",
    'retina2'   : "only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-resolution: 192dpi)",
    'retina3'   : "only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (min-resolution: 288dpi)",
    'landscape' : "screen and (orientation:landscape) ",    
    'portrait'  : "screen and (orientation:portrait) "
);

@mixin for_breakpoint($breakpoints) {
    $conditions : ();
    @each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {
      // If the key exists in the map
      @if map-has-key($media_queries, $breakpoint) {
        $conditions: append(
            $conditions,
            #{inspect(map-get($media_queries, $breakpoint))},
            comma
        );
      }
      @else {
        @warn "Unfortunately, no value could be retrieved from `#{$breakpoint}`. "
        + "Please make sure it is defined in `$breakpoints` map.";
      }
    }

    @media #{$conditions} {
        @content;
    }

}
```

And us it like this in my scss:

```
#masthead {
    background: white;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    @include for_breakpoint(mobile desktop) {
        height:70px;
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
    }
}
```

and that outputs this:

```
#masthead { 
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  height: 90px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 667px), only screen and (min-width: 1025px) { 
  #masthead {
    height: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```